# How to reshape matrix in MathNet?

Tags: c#, reshape, mathnet-numerics

I have 1x4 Matrix
`[1, 2, 3, 4]`
And I want to get 2x2 Matrix
`[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`. How can achieve this in Math.Net?

I found `Resize` method, which does not what I need.

```
Vector<double> vector = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
var matrix1x4 = vector1x4.ToRowMatrix();
var matrix2x2 = matrix1x4.Resize(2, 2);
```

`Resize` method does not reshape, it copies part "common" part for those two matrices and discards the rest

```
[[1, 0], [2, 0]]
```

Comment: `Matrix<double> matrix2 = matrix1.Reshape(2, 2);` ?

Comment: where is that `Reshape` from? I have no such a function available [here](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex32/Matrix.htm)